# How many users are completely new to Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, new-users

Hello, I've recently came across [this user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/826) who has no linked accounts at all, yet has asked questions, followed, etc. It is these users that I would say is a measure of how "mainstream" area51 is becoming. But how many users like that are there? Almost every user I see has accounts on SO, Meta, and others.

Is there any kind of way to figure out how many users on Area 51 do not have any linked accounts?

Comment: Would vote up till infinity if possible.

Answer (score 5):

There are only a couple of thousand unique visitors on Area51 so far. Compared to the nearly 8 million unique visitors on Stack Overflow, I think it's a WEE bit premature to imply that Area51 is "mainstream!"