# What is the minimum length of time a proposed site will be in its beta phase?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

When "committing" to a proposed site, I see the following language:

> I commit . . . to visit at least three times per week, to ask at least three questions during the beta phase, and to answer as many questions as I can for at least three months.

How long does this beta phase last?  I understand that this project is still evolving.  However, if I'm expected to commit to a certain level of activity during the beta phase, I need to know what the minimum amount of time I will have in order to meet my obligation.

(I realize this sounds like nitpicking and if the actual phrasing was more vague, I wouldn't care.  However, since it quantifies the minimum level of interactions I must have, I feel it should also quantify the amount of time I have to complete those interactions.)

Comment: 6-8 weeks. Your value of 6-8 weeks may vary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Current plans (subject to change, but probably in the ballpark):

- **Private beta, 1 week**. Committers and "special committer invitations" only. Goal is to populate the site with representative questions and answers, so it looks and works like what it's supposed to be (and we can work out any showstopping issues) before we open the doors to the public.
- **Public beta. At least 1 month, possibly many more.** Open to any users on the internet. Goal is to see what kind of traction the site gets, and what kind of Q&A it attracts.

During the public beta, there will be checkpoints the site has to make in key metrics for us to decide that it's viable and fits with our mission of ...

> make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions

We haven't decided exactly what those metrics will be, yet. We have ideas, yes, but nothing I'm comfortable sharing in detail at the moment.

Comment: If that's really the goal of all this, then I think you should promote referrals outrageously. That's the only way more than 15 proposals from the site are actually going to turn into real sites (judging by how things look now).

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/how-many-users-are-completely-new-to-area51

(No referrals) == (No non-SO people).

Comment: Have you decided on metrics yet, or is that covered somewhere else?

Comment: @baka see http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/221/what-happens-now