# How long is a proposal expected to be in beta before going live?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase, live-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the minimum length of time a proposed site will be in its beta phase?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54633/what-is-the-minimum-length-of-time-a-proposed-site-will-be-in-its-beta-phase)

Will there be an indicator? How will it be measured? Traffic? Quantity of questions? Answer velocity?

Can you give us a preview while we wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54633/what-is-the-minimum-length-of-time-a-proposed-site-will-be-in-its-beta-phase/54705#54705) a similar question, a few days ago.

> During the public beta, there will be checkpoints the site has to make in key metrics for us to decide that it's viable and fits with our mission of ...
>
> *make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions*
>
> We haven't decided exactly what those metrics will be, yet. We have ideas, yes, but nothing I'm comfortable sharing in detail at the moment.

So basically, they won't really say, but they want to see that the sites live up to overall SE goals.

Comment: It's not like "we won't say" because it is a secret. It's more like "we can't say, yet" because it is simply too early to apply numbers to the process. The SE 2.0 sites haven’t even launched, yet, and we'll have a much better idea of what *works* when we have real, empirical data to work with.